# urlrewriter.net project stopped?

Tags: urlrewriter.net

I just tried to download the URL rewriting module from urlrewriter.net but the website has been replaced by a standard PLESK page.

Has the development of this tool been shut down or is it just a temporary downtime?
Could anyone provide the current version of the tool? That would help me a lot since the module is used in the book I am currently reading about SEO.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download link (v 1.6):
http://www.brothersoft.com/urlrewriter.net-117841.html

I can't confirm if they are dead or not, but google pages show up 3 dead links so I guess so...

Answer (score 1):

The Url Routing engine developed for ASP.NET MVC [could now be used](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx) in classic ASP.NET WebForms applications.